# How to make the simplest software-controlled ON/OFF hardware with Java?

Tags: java, hardware, hardware-interface

I want to make the simplest and most reliable on/off device controlled from a compuer software (Java).

I was thinking about sinus sound singnal + RC filter with relay for specific frequency, but unfortunatelly **I can't use sound card** - it is already occupied for different purposes.

How can I achieve this without much compatibility/reliability issues. **It should work both on Unix and Windows**

I mean an output device, so I want to turn on/off relay from Java software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USB MIDI adapter and then midi to relay .

Comment: I propably don't precised enough ot misunderstood you - I want an output device - turn on/off relay from java program.

Comment: I see a midi-out possibility but how to transform midi signal to simple 0/1 singnal from such output http://www.ausmidi.com/images/G2M-MIDI%20OUT.JPG ?

Comment: http://www.midisolutions.com/prodrel.htm for example.

Comment: Accepted - I think that RC filter + relay is simpler, but this seems to be most simple alternative and without compilacted custom hardware.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe use a Raspberry Pi (includes GPIO controller). Put a web service to control the GPIO. The web service is accesable from any HTTP client.

http://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-4-gpio-setup/

Comment: Nice solution, propably very reliable, but a little bit overenginered for "on/off" switch I think.